# Medium Blob in DataGrid ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datagrid, dataset

I am currently trying to display data from a table in a MySQL Database using a DataGrid component in ASP.net C#.

Its displaying all of the columns which are in int and varchar format but one column is a mediumblob format which contains only text.

I am binding the DataGrid to a DataSet from the MySQL table using the following

```
public void loadGrid(string query, GridView tblGrid)
    {
        using (DatabaseWork db = new DatabaseWork())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.conn))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    tblGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    tblGrid.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }
```

For some reason the Medium blob is never being shown and no exception is being thrown.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Francis Gilbert. Looking at the post I thought it would make more sense as I am only going to be storing text in the field is to the field TINYTEXT instead of TINYBLOB. Doing this fixes the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to process the BLOB first. For a bit of help, have a look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html